# Is there p-value associated with residual?

Tags: regression, machine-learning

I am performing a simple linear regression where `y = income` and `x = education`. I was just wondering if there exists p-value associated with the residual `e` in linear regression model to test its statistical significance. How does one obtain the p-value?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why do you think you want such a $p$-value?

Comment: I want such a p-value because I want to find some portion of `income` that's not explained by `education`.

Comment: Interesting.  I suggest thinking about what assumptions must be in place in order for any p-value to be calculated...and then whether such assumptions could be made to apply to your situation.

Comment: In that case you do not want those $p$-values. Instead you are looking for $R^2$: this is the proportion of the variance in `income` explained by `education`, so $1-R^2$ is the proportion of the varinace in `income` not explained by `education`.

Comment: The standard error of estimate may be of interest too.

Comment: @rolando2 Can I perform a statistically significance test of residual by calculating the confidence interval of residual, `mean of residuals +- (1.96* standard error of residuals)`?

Comment: (Note that in linear regression, the mean of residuals always takes the same value.)  If you want to demonstrate that certain residuals exceed the mean residual by >abs(1.96 standard deviations), that should be easy to do.  Given N observations, you have N opportunities for that to occur, and in a large data set you'll routinely have residuals out at 3 and 3.5 standard deviations.  It's hard to see how these would yield a meaningful p-value tailored to any question.  OTOH, you may find it profitable to look into *influential points* for what they do signify.

Comment: If a residual is radically different from the rest -- say, 8 SD from 0 -- the p-value associated with that (using your approach) is evidence that the data point doesn't belong.  As in a study of 10,000 mosquitoes and 1 tiger.

Comment: Use the F test for the regression.  It's standard: its assumptions, limitations, and applications are discussed well in all textbooks about least squares regression.  Just about all statistical regression software will automatically output the F statistic and its p-value, too.